# Word 2016- VBA- How To Insert Row Below Selected Row In A Table?

Tags: vba, ms-word, insert, rows

The following code inserts a row above the selected row in a table.  How do I insert a row below the selected row in a table?

I tried `Set oNewRow = Selection.InsertRowsBelow` but it generates a compile error "Expected Function or Variable".

```
Dim oTable As Table
Dim ocell As Cell
Dim oCC As ContentControl
Dim oNewRow As Row
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)    
    Set oNewRow = Selection.Rows.Add
    Set ocell = oNewRow.Cells(1)
    Set oCC = Selection.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText, ocell.Range)
            With oCC
            .DefaultTextStyle = "Style1"
            .Tag = "Test1"
            .Setplaceholdertext , , "test1"
            If oCC.ShowingPlaceholderText Then
                 With ActiveDocument.Styles("Placeholder Text").Font
                       .Name = "Arial"
                       .Size = 8
                       .ColorIndex = wdRed
                       .Italic = True
                End With
            End If
        End With  
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: By inserting a row above the next row?

Comment: Below whichever row is selected in a table

Comment: Yes, so insert a row above the next row in the table.

Comment: I tried ```Set oNewRow = Selection.InsertRowsBelow``` and it still gives me compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is trivial! I have to wonder how much effort you're investing in this:

```
Selection.InsertRowsBelow
```

If you want to replicate a row - which is what your content control code suggests - see any of:

https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/27809-code-add-new-row-table.html#post87989

https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/13955-macro-add-row-table-word-form.html#post38461

https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43603-multiple-dependent-dropdown-lists-table-add-new.html#post145675

Comment: I know it is trivial and the answer is staring at me lol!  I have been looking everywhere. 
 My brain feels like jello. Maybe I have been looking at the computer screen too long.  I tried ```Selection.InsertRowsBelow``` but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Is your *Selection* in a table? I have already given you code to check that.

Comment: Yes selection is in a table. I already tried ```oNewRow = Selection.Information(wdWithInTable).InsertRowsBelow``` but that didn't work hence why I am still stumped.. :-/

Comment: That's clearly *NOT* how the code I gave you was implemented... The code as posted above works just fine IF the selection is in a table, regardless, even, of whether that table has merged cells. the correct implementation would be: `Dim Rw As Row : Selection.InsertRowsBelow : Set Rw = Selection.Rows(1)`. If, however, your table has vertically-merged cells, you cannot set a row reference to any row. You could, however, use: `Dim Rng As Range : Selection.InsertRowsBelow : Set Rng = Selection.Range`

Comment: Well then....it all makes sense now.  Finally got it.  Thank you so much sir for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

Per Macropod

```
Dim oTable As Table
Dim ocell As Cell
Dim oCC As ContentControl
Dim oNewRow As Row
    Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
        **Selection.InsertRowsBelow
    Set oNewRow = Selection.Rows(1)**
    
    Set ocell = oNewRow.Cells(1)
    Set oCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlRichText, ocell.Range)
    With oCC
        .DefaultTextStyle = "Style1"
        .Tag = "test1"
        .SetPlaceholderText , , "test1"
        If oCC.ShowingPlaceholderText Then
             With ActiveDocument.Styles("Placeholder Text").Font
                   .Name = "Arial"
                   .Size = 8
                   .ColorIndex = wdRed
                   .Italic = True
            End With
        End If
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
```