# Insert a row above a selected row in a table

Tags: vba, ms-word, row

I know, I have seen this link: [Word 2016- VBA- How To Insert Row Below Selected Row In A Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65205358/word-2016-vba-how-to-insert-row-below-selected-row-in-a-table)
But, unfortunately, even if it may be trivial, I don't understand how to do it.

Here is what I want to do: 1)to add row(s) (from docSource) at the end of a Table (first part working well) OR 2)to add row(s) (from docSource) above the selected row (row selected on docTarget) (second part struggling to find the right way).

```
Dim docTarget As Document
Dim docSource As Document
Set docTarget = ActiveDocument
Set docSource = Documents.Open(strFileName)

IF SOMETHING THEN
    '1) Working code
    Dim myRange As Object
    Set myRange = docTarget.Content
    myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    myRange.FormattedText = docSource.Tables(2).Range.FormattedText
ELSE
    '2) Can't figure it out
    Dim myRange2 As Object
    Set myRange2 = docTarget.Content
    
    myRange2.Select 'What? - the row I already highlighted -
    Selection.InsertRowsBelow

    myRange2.FormattedText = docSource.Tables(2).Range.FormattedText
ENDIF

docSource.Close (0)
Set docSource = Nothing
Set docTarget = Nothing
```

For information, my tables from docSource or docTarget got 3 columns and no merge cells.

I welcome any ideas or tips.

Thanks.

Comment: Why aren’t you using Intellisense, the Object Browser, or the online help? If you had used any of those you would have discovered [`InsertRowsAbove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertrowsabove)

Comment: As you can see in the code above, I am aware of this property (actually, I use below instead of above, but same principle), but I don't know how to use it in my case. When you use wdCollapseEnd, you go at the end of the document, then you can add/merge rows at the end, but when you want to add rows in the middle of a table, you need a starting point (row highlighted or cursor position from user) to add rows above/below. I don't know how to position it as for example something.Select, then I could use Selection.InsertRowsAbove. Hope you understand my issue. Word object not always logic for me.

Comment: Your question indicates that you would already have a row selected before the code is run. `Selection.Information(wdWithInTable)` will tell you if the selection is in a table and `Selection.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)` will tell you the row number. If you need to select a specific row you can do this using `Tables(n).Rows(n).Select`, though you should really try to avoid using `Selection`.

Comment: This Information property seems interesting, but I am not there yet. I try `MsgBox (docTarget.Content)` which gave a window with the full table, but `MsgBox (docTarget.Content.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber))` gave me -1 instead of 3 as I selected the row 3 before clicking the button on my userform.  I am always trying to avoid the words Selection & Select (I got this good advice before), but these words come often when you use a macro for help. Anyway, I think you gave me the right direction with Information property. Just need to find out how to connect it with myRange2.

Comment: I already showed you how to use it in my comment. `docTarget.Content.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)` has no connection to what you have you selected. `docTarget.Content` refers to the ***entire*** content of the document, so checking its row number makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't clever, but I was trying something else as `Msgbox(Selection.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber))` gave me also the number -1.

Comment: `Msgbox(Selection.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber))` Actually, I can make it work when it is in a separate macro and run the macro from the Developer Ribbon, but if I call this macro via the click on a button on my userform, it doesn't work. Not sure to understand why, but the code is certainly alright.

Comment: Maybe I should get the information before opening my userform and then use this information once the userform is open. Or am I talking rubbish? The highlighted row may be not visible when the userform is open which will explain why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer, thanks to the patience of Timothy Rylatt. But if you have any positive critics or improvements (better coding), please do not hesitate to comment.

First, before opening my userform, I got this:

```
mySelectedRow = Selection.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)
```

mySlectedRow declare as Public

Second, in the userform, I got this:

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
Dim strFileName As String
strFileName = ActiveDocument.Path & "\something\" & cboFileOption.Text
' Open selected item as docSource and assign docTarget to this document
Dim docTarget As Document
Dim docSource As Document
Set docTarget = ActiveDocument
Set docSource = Documents.Open(strFileName)
' Fill docTarget with the content of docSource
Dim myRange As Object
Set myRange = docTarget.Content
If Me.optEndTable.Value = True Then
    myRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    myRange.FormattedText = docSource.Tables(2).Range.FormattedText
Else
    docSource.Tables(2).Range.FormattedText.Copy
    docTarget.Content.Tables(1).Rows(mySelectedRow).Select
    Selection.Rows(Selection.Rows.Count).Range.Paste
End If
' Close selected item (docSource) without saving
docSource.Close (0)
Set docSource = Nothing
Set docTarget = Nothing
' End
Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Hope that make sense.
Thanks